# In OpenBSD, what is a service?

Tags: openbsd

I am trying to understand some fundamentals that I had some misunderstandings on, and in looking at OpenBSD I find that I'm not clear what a service is. (Note that I am not referring to web services, such as listed in `/etc/services`).

In [rcctl(08)](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-6.9/rcctl):

> **NAME** 
>     **rcctl** — configure and control daemons and services

> **DESCRIPTION** 
>     The **rcctl** utility can enable or disable a base system service or a base system or package daemon...

In [rc.conf(8)](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-6.9/rc.conf):

> ... 
> **DESCRIPTION** 
> ... 
>     **Base system service** configuration variables control features available by default that are not implemented as daemons. They can be set to either **YES** or **NO**. When set to **YES**, they have the following effects: 
> ...

From `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
...
# services related to RPC, NFS, and YP
amd_flags=NO            # also see amd_master below
lockd_flags=NO
mountd_flags=NO
nfsd_flags=NO
portmap_flags=NO        # note: inetd(8) rpc services need portmap too
statd_flags=NO
ypbind_flags=NO
ypldap_flags=NO
ypserv_flags=NO

# set the following to "YES" to turn them on
pf=YES                  # Packet filter / NAT
ipsec=NO                # IPsec
check_quotas=YES        # NO may be desirable in some YP environments
accounting=NO           # process accounting (using /var/account/acct)

# Multicast routing configuration
# Please look at netstart(8) for a detailed description if you change these
multicast=NO            # Reject IPv4 multicast packets by default

# miscellaneous other flags
amd_master=/etc/amd/master      # AMD 'master' map
library_aslr=YES                # set to NO to disable library randomization
savecore_flags=                 # "-z" to compress
spamd_black=NO                  # set to YES to run spamd without greylisting
shlib_dirs=                     # extra directories for ldconfig, separated
                                # by space
...
```

So when OpenBSD is referring to a service in this context, what is it?

Comment: Are you asking because you are confused by something? Could you explicitly point out what your issue is?  Do you understand `sshd` (the SSH server) and `ntpd` (the NTP daemon) as services? I'm just trying to get you to limit the scope of the question, because now it is so wide that it's unclear whether we need to explain the concept of a daemon, system accounts, networking, and other basic operating system concepts.

Comment: @they Maybe if I reworded it as "Base system service"? Because I'm not clear, for example, why a base system service can only be `ON`/`OFF` while the daemons can have various options (flags). This is about how the word is being used here, because I'm not understanding it.

Comment: So the question is about the meaning of "daemon" vs. the meaning of "service"?

Answer (score -1):

The rc.conf seems to refer mainly to daemons, but the packet filter is a network feature activated by `rcctl` too. See https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/config.html

Then a service seems to be anything which is control by `rcctl`, daemon or not. Note - see https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/usr.sbin/rcctl/rcctl.sh - that `rcctl` is mainly a wrapper script for `/etc/rc.d` scripts.

I am a bit puzzled. The `/etc/rc.d/` directory seems to contain only daemons. I think `rcctl enable pf` use directly the `/etc/rc` (which happens to deal with `pf`). I guess another services which are not daemon are `ipsec`, `accounting`…

Comment: If I understand it, `/etc/rc.d/` contains the scripts run by `/etc/rc` as configured in `/etc/rc.conf` and `/etc/rc.conf.local`. The `rcctl` command is used for configuration of these files and controlling the daemons and services, AFAICT. I think when using `enable`, it makes the appropriate change based on the command. As far as actually starting `pf`, for example, `/etc/rc` uses `pfctl` (I can see with `grep pf /etc/rc`). So I can see those other services listed, I just am trying to understand what differentiates them from to be base system services - I literally don't understand the term.

Comment: I read « system service or a base system or package daemon », then system service (`pf`…), base system daemon (`dhcpd`…), package daemon (anything added afterward with a package). But what is the more important is to know what can you do with `rcctl`… actual meanings are less important.